# Forgot to check "GNOME" desktop while installing Kail Linux

Tags: kali-linux, gnome

Well, I've just reinstalled Kali Linux on my virtual machine but I forgot to check the GNOME , and now I'm only able to enter xfce and default session.

I know i cat install gnome desktop on my OS using `apt install kali-desktop-gnome`
but the last time I installed Kali Linux i didn't download anything, It just got installed because I checked that check bar ...

My guess is that `kali-desktop-gnome` files are somewhere inside my Kali installation ISO file.

is there a way to install gnome desktop on my Kali without downloading it? (or reinstalling the whole OS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt` allows using local directories as repositories:

1. Mount the iso file to e.g. `/mnt`

   ```
   mount -o loop /path/to/install.iso /mnt
   ```
2. Add the location to the repositories

   ...by adding this line to `/etc/apt/sources.list` (best as first entry):

   ```
   deb [allow-insecure=yes] file:/mnt kali-rolling main contrib non-free
   ```
3. Run `apt update` and then install the desired packages.

Comment: I tried it but it say's /mnt is not a signed package ; (/mnt is in my home)

Comment: @YoloWex - my bad. one needs to explicitly allow "insecure" sources in the `sources.list`-entry. See update.

Comment: Thank's Dude it really worked!! You are a life savior!

Comment: Do you know the reason im getting negative votes here?

Comment: @YoloWex Maybe have a severe read of [this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/) - Kali is meant for the specific purpose of penetration testing but not for running it as daily OS. You not knowing how to add a local repository leads to the assumption that you may not be the target audience of said distribution and this is viewed quite critically here. Especially the idea of you depending on a check box may give off the impression of you being a freshman/greenhorn. Additionally, the question can be seen as lacking own initiative - maybe an internet search could have solved it.